# Vendor prefixes for javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, vendor-prefix

I'm new to this world of coding. My knowledge of HTML and CSS is minimum and inexistent when it comes to Javascript.

I am working on a project for which I need to create a parallax site and each section is divided diagonally. The parallax bit is almost done but I'm struggling to make the diagonals functional on different browsers. Using a bit of code somebody else put in this forum I got to do it for Firefox but still need to make it work on the other browsers or at least Chrome and Safari. Can anyone help?

HTML

```
<div>
  <section><a href="#1"></a></section>
  <section><a href="#2"></a></section>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body, div{ height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
div { overflow : hidden; position: relative;  }
section { 
height        : 500%;
background    : red; 
width         : 500%;
position      : absolute;
top           : -100%;
-moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
-o-transform-origin: 0 0;
-ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
transform-origin: 0 0;
}

section + section { 
background: #333;    
top       : 80%;
-moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
-o-transform-origin: 0 0;
-ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
transform-origin: 0 0;
} 

section a { display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; cursor: pointer; }
```

JS

```
$(function() {

$(window).on('resize', function() {
   var h = $(document).height(),
       w = $(document).width(); 

   var angle = ((Math.atan(h/w) * 10.29577951308232));
   $('section').css("-moz-transform", "rotate(" + angle + "deg)")

})
.triggerHandler('resize');
});
```

Comment: You're only targeting the moz transform property? I'm presuming if you change moz to WebKit it will work in chrome?

Comment: jQuery 1.8+ automatically adds vendor prefixes.

Comment: Leaksterr, I tried that but still not doing it...

Comment: Rob W, I just added JQuery 1.8 but nothing is happening on Chrome... I'm going mad. I thought It'd have a really easy fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rob W. pointed out, jQuery will (in recent versions) add vendor prefixes for you. However, that means you shouldn't do it yourself:

```
$('section').css("transform", "rotate(" + angle + "deg)");
```

This works in both Chrome and Firefox for me: <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7L6AV/1/)</kbd>